# return value in constructors to avoid dupplications in code

Tags: php, oop

As far as I know, constructors don't return values. The problem I'm facing below is, I have to repeat calling `check_error()` in every method of child class to see if parent `$error` array has any errors in it or not.

Is there any chance changing my code to remove replications to make it more user friendly and maintainable?

Thanks

```
class RestfulRequest extends Restful
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();

     if (is_array($this->error))
     {
        return 'Error found';
     }
  }
..
..
..
}
```

I know the code above is not possible but I'm just adding to show you what I needed in first place. No repetition, just one check in every initiations.

```
abstract class Restful
{
  public $error = array('error1', 'error2');
  abstract public function check_error();
  abstract public function method_one();
  abstract public function method_two();
}

class RestfulRequest extends Restful
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
  }

  public function check_error()
  {
     return (is_array($this->error)) ? false : true;
  }

  public function method_one()
  {
     if ($this->check_error() === false)
     {
        return 'Error found';
     }

     return 'No error';
  }

  public function method_two()
  {
     if ($this->check_error() === false)
     {
        return 'Error found';
     }

     return 'No error';
  }
}

$obj_restful = new RestfulRequest();
echo $obj_restful->method_one();
echo $obj_restful->method_two();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors can't return values, but they can throw exceptions.

```
Class RestfulRequest extends Restful
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();

     if (is_array($this->error))
     {
        throw new Exception('Error found.');
     }
  }
..
..
..
}
```

Comment: A question: Would `$obj_restful->method_one();` and `$obj_restful->method_two();` be ignored (canceled) immediately if error found in Constructor?

Comment: That largely depends how you handle the exception.